# Search View Suggestions doesn't work with 2 toolbars

Tags: android, xml, searchview, search-suggestion

Good Morning Sirs

I was able to reproduce the WhatsApp search bar as you can see in the image below:

For this I created two toolbars and two menus as shown below:

**menu_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

**menu_search.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />
</menu>
```

**Toolbar inside activity_main.xml**

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Toolbar inside search_toolbar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/searchtoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:background="@color/colorTextPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

I implemented SearchRecentSuggestions however it was not working, doing some tests I saw that it was only working if I use the inflate in the menu_search directly in the onCreateMenuOptions, however,I end up losing the animation as it is shown in the image below:

[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQG2.png)

[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/020n2.png)

**Code Used**

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();
    sView = searchView;
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I tried to inflate the menu_search after the menu_items but also did not get the expected result.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);

    Toolbar searchTool = findViewById(R.id.searchtoolbar);
    searchTool.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_search);
    Menu searchM = searchTool.getMenu();
    SearchView itemS = (SearchView)searchM.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    sView = itemS;
    itemS.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    itemS.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return true;
}
```

[Case 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbrHp.png)

Doing an analysis I could see that it is not registering what I am typing in SearchView because after I returned from the normal test, after registering a few words, they appeared in the design with the animation.

[Case 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZw84.png)

Is there any possibility that I can inflate the two menus or enable this registry in this second toolbar and achieve this?

[Case 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzRhz.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I got it find a solution for this problem.

First of all it is not possible inflate two menus in onCreateMenuOptions, so to achieve the behavior of SearchSuggestion in this situation only create a method in my case handleSearch and put in the SearchListener and the problem with the Search Suggestion will be solved.